# Update design workflow in Talend at runtime

Tags: etl, talend

I am very much new in Talend ETL tool.

I have a very basic question: Can I update the design workflow and transformation in Talend ETL tool at runtime?

I mean suppose my application is running in a server. Now I want to change the design workflow of the running application so the application will be updated to new design workflow at runtime. Similary I want to change the transformation logic at runtime. I think MuleSoft provides this provision.

Please need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on what kind of functionalities you wanted to change during the runtime. You cannot change complete transformation logic. There are few possibilities and it depends on your requirement

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jim Macaulay said in a comment, it depends on what you want to change.

- Is it the columns that a row contains ?

Then you might need Dynamic Schema which is a paid feature (or use different flows, see next part).

- Is it simply to alternate between 2 distinct datasources (or X
  different flows) based on external stimulii ?

Then you could use the If trigger with context variables to use one or the other.